# FCM Chrome notifications styling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Hi I have successfully implemented FCM, firebase cloud messaging. I want to display the notifications with enlarged image like its mentioned here in demo of Image
https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/

But the notification always displays as its default theme. Below is firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-messaging.js");

var config = {
            apiKey: "API KEY",
            authDomain: "MY AUTH DOMAIN",
            databaseURL: "MY DB URL",
            projectId: "MY PROJECT",
            storageBucket: "MY STORAGE BUCKET",
            messagingSenderId: "809524248057"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
        var data = JSON.parse(payload);

        const title = data.title;
        const options = {
          image: data.icon
        };
        self.registration.showNotification(title, options);

        /*self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
          body: data.body,
          icon: data.icon,
          click_action: data.click_action,
          time_to_live: data.time_to_live,
          data: data.data,
          tag: data.tag
      });*/
});
```

I am new to this so probably Im missing something. Any help is appreciated, Thanks